# Parallax Scrolling Stops Working in Chrome When Using NextGen Gallery on Website

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, wordpress

I've already reached out to NextGen support but they will not help.  So given that, I'm having an issue with the parallax scrolling on a website.  I'm trying to add a NextGen Album and the scrolling stops working right in Chrome.  In other browsers, I'm not having an issue at all.

This site design is not mine and I am picking through it now and running into this issue so I'm still discovering new treats daily in the code.  I've not run into this browser specific issue yet and I'm at a loss for what could be causing the issues.  Any thoughts or comments are greatly welcomed.  Thank you!

The link to the site: http://npdavenport.x10host.com/k9solutionstesting/about-k9/graduation-gallery/

Comment: your server is down...

Comment: It seems to be back up now.  It's just a test site while I work though this issue so it's a bit flaky.